# Compile debug as 32 bit and release as 64 bit c#

Tags: c#, build, console-application

I am creating a console application which will depend on certain installed files belonging to another piece of software.

On my local machine, the 32 bit version of that software is installed. On the servers, the 64 bit version is installed.

There is nothing I can do to change this. I can not install the 64 bit version locally (due to reasons I can't comprehend, but no doubt somebody somewhere thinks it must be a good idea).

Is there a way to have the debug build as 32 bit and release as 64 bit? Currently I am having to change it every time I want to copy up and then change it back.

I am using C# in VS 2019

Comment: Do you have build server? Then you have a perfect reason to setup one.

Comment: Why do you think this is not possible? I never actually needed to do that but isn't the platform target changeable per configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Solution Properties -> Configuration manager` you can configure target platform for debug and release mode.